# Compare common values ​between a stack and a list

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

Good night, I'm having trouble comparing the common values ​​of a list and a stack, could you help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

**Note: I'm a beginner**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack<Integer> pilha = new Stack<Integer>();
    pilha.push(15);
    pilha.push(20);
    pilha.push(35);
    pilha.push(45);

    LinkedList<Integer> lista = new LinkedList<>();
    lista.addLast(41);
    lista.addLast(23);
    lista.addLast(20);
    lista.addLast(12);

    System.out.println("Os numeros da Pilha são:" + pilha);
    System.out.println("Os numeros da Pilha são:" + lista);


    int sPilha = pilha.size();
    int valor =0;
    int valorLista = 0;
    int verd = 0;
    for(int cont =0; cont < sPilha; cont++) {
        valor = pilha.pop();
        valorLista  = lista.pop();

        if(valor == valorLista){
            verd = valorLista;
            System.out.println("Os valores em comum da lista são: " + valorLista);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: a) pop - Removes the object at the top of this stack and returns that object as the value of this function.
b) need an inner loop I think

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This should tell you all you need to know: https://www.baeldung.com/java-lists-intersection

Answer (score 1):

Like wombat mentioned in the comment

1. pop alters the content of stack and linkedlist
2. you need to compare every element in stack to every other element in linked list like so

```
        for(int cont =0; cont < pilha.size(); cont++) {
            valor = pilha.get(cont);
            for(int i =0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                valorLista  = lista.get(i);
                if(valor == valorLista){
                    verd = valorLista;
                    System.out.println("Os valores em comum da lista são: " + valorLista);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could also use `if (lista.contains(valor)){ ...`

Answer (score 0):

*pop* method removes the element from list or stack (read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html#pop()).

If you don't want to remove element, access it using *get* method:

```
        for(int cont = 0; cont < pilha.size(); cont++) {
            valor = pilha.get(cont);
            if(lista.contains(valor)) {
                System.out.println("Os valores em comum da lista são: " + valor);
            }
        }
```